# How to create a database schema from models when database fields required are in JSON?

Tags: loopbackjs

Currently, I have set few JSON fields as "object" in model but I want these fields to be JSON in database. However, when I am auto migrating it, fields are getting created as text in MySQL? How to fix this?

```
"education": {
    "type": "object"
},
"technology": {
    "type": "object"
},
"certificationsAndAchievements": {
    "type": "object"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [mysql](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/MySQL-connector.html#using-thedatatypefieldcolumn-option-with-mysql) option on your models and set `dataType` to `JSON`.  Now when you migrate it this will be the column type

```
{
  "education": {
    "type": "object",
    "mysql": {
      "dataType":"JSON"
    }
  },
  "technology": {
    "type": "object",
    "mysql": {
      "dataType":"JSON"
    }
  },
  "certificationsAndAchievements": {
    "type": "object",
    "mysql": {
      "dataType":"JSON"
    }
  }
}
```